# Vidalia was unable to start Tor. permission problem

Tags: tor

The exact message is:

> Vidalia was unable to start Tor. Check your settings to ensure the
>   correct name and  location of your Tor executable is specified.

Tor exists but vidalia couldn't see or read it. I click "Browse" & it says:

> Unable to save bookmarks in
>   /home/me/.kde/share/apps/kfileplaces/bookmarks.xml.

Reported error was:

> Unable to open temporary file.. This error message will only be 
>   shown once. The cause of the error needs to be fixed as quickly as
>   possible, which is  most likely a full hard drive.

I added `rwx` permissions but problem doesn't resolve. I tried to run it as `su`, but there is problem with fontconfig & vidalia couldn't connect to x-server.

Of course I can use tor with tor-browser.

I use Kubuntu 12.10, vidalia 0.2.2. (I have seen this problem recently in Ubuntu 12.04 as well).

Comment: Can you have a look into your `vidalia.conf` and write what value `TorExecutable` has?

Comment: default value : /usr/sbin/tor

Answer (score 5):

How did you go about "installing" tor / vidalia? I'd recommend these steps:

- Download the [**Tor Browser Bundle**](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html)
- learn [How to verify signatures for packages](https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en)
- and thoroughly study [Want Tor to **really** work?](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html#warning)
- Further, note that [Torbutton is deprecated/dead](https://www.torproject.org/torbutton/).

Answer (score 2):

Launchpad has the entry »[Vidalia was unable to start Tor. Check your settings to ensure the correct name and location of your Tor executable is specified.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vidalia/+bug/680192)« It seems that you hit the same bug. You can resolve this issue by downloading the [AppArmor profile for Vidalia](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/124592147/apparmor-profile). Copy it to `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.vidalia`. Or you can also open the existing file and add the line:

```
/usr/sbin/tor Ux,
```

See the [diff](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/124592488/apparmor-profile-patched). Now Vidalia is able to start Tor.

However as [nutty about natty](https://askubuntu.com/users/16023/nutty-about-natty) [wrote](https://askubuntu.com/a/262656/236) you should better use the Tor Browser Bundle. Usually this gives you a higher degree of anonymity.

Comment: broken link "AppArmor profile for Vidalia"

Answer (score -1):

1- open terminal

2- run: # sudo -sH

3- copy the vidalia icon to your Desktop

4- run: # cd Desktop

5- run: # sudo open vidalia

thats it!