# Tor fails to start

Tags: 13.04, tor

When i run Vidalia this is first thing appears in picture below

i also saw [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262593/vidalia-was-unable-to-start-tor-permission-problem) and [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vidalia/+bug/680192)
and applied them and they didn't work
anyone can help please ??
[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You better read Log.

Thereafter, use [google](https://encrypted.google.com/) to get answer, what actually happens.

If you still can't start your Tor. You must append full log and full of your config (Settings). You can do it via [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/), to reduce size of your question. Edit this question to get answer.